# Why does grouping or moving textboxes break the script?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, indesign-scripting

I am a beginner at writing scripts for InDesign (just started today!). I have somehow managed to write a script which auto-fills a text box with a list of the linked images within the document. However, when I group the text box with other objects or move it to another indesign doc, the script no longer works. I get an error that says "Object is invalid" with the source being "resFrame.contents = res.String;". Can someone please explain why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Code below...

```
myDoc = app.activeDocument;  
myPages = myDoc.pages.everyItem().getElements();  
myDoc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = myDoc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.INCHES;  

for (var k = 0; k < myPages.length; k++) {  
    resString = myDoc.links.everyItem().name.join("\r");  
    resFrame = myFramelinks(myPages[k]);  
    resFrame.contents =  resString;
    }  

function myFramelinks (page) {
    var mFlinks = page.textFrames.item("linkslist");
    return mFlinks;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Where does your items name "linkslist" come from? By setting a name for the textFrame?

The "name" property of a textframe seems to be persistent for the document. Also if you copy paste the textframe to another doc it still is there.

But if you have a page with 2 textframes and you run:

```
$.writeln(app.activeDocument.pages[0].textFrames.length);
```

it will return 2

Group these textframes together and it will return 0

If you want to access elements that are grouped you need to access them like this:

```
$.writeln (app.activeDocument.pages[0].groups[0].textFrames[0].name)
```

You also can access them this way:

```
$.writeln(app.activeDocument.pages[0].allPageItems.length)
```

This will return 3.

if you run:

```
for(var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.pages[0].allPageItems.length; i++){
  $.writeln(app.activeDocument.pages[0].allPageItems[i].constructor.name)
}
```

The output will be:

```
Group
TextFrame
TextFrame
```

So you could create a check for your name and access that particular textFrame again.

(Tested in ID CC 2014 on OSX 10.10.2)

**Update:**

To retrieve the textframe with the name "linkslist" you should do something like this:

```
function get_linklist(page) {
  var tf = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < page.allPageItems.length; i++) {
    var item = page.allPageItems[i];
    if (item.name == "linkslist") {
      tf = item;
      break;
    }
  }
  return tf;
}

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var p = doc.pages[0];

var res = get_linklist(p);
if (res === null) {
  $.writeln(" :(");
} else {
  $.writeln(" :)");
}
```

Comment: Hi fabian, thanks for the input. I am having some difficulty incorporating this into my script - can you elaborate?

Comment: I updated the post with some example code.

Comment: so, the key is to iterate through an object (allPageItems) which doesn't cloak the text frames?

Comment: Exactly, if the textFrame is in the group he is a child of the group and not accessible via  the textFrames collection

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much. On another note, do you know how I can get the script to not list duplicate links?

Comment: ask a new question so we don't mix up topics. ;-)